# Remote Desktop Connetion

Tags: remote-desktop, raspberrypi, 20.10

I have a raspberry pi 4 installed with ubuntu 20.10 and a laptop installed with ubuntu 20.10.
How to connect rpi4 to my laptop using rdp?

Comment: I connected RPI using ssh and it worked. But I can't rdp RPI to ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-remote-desktop/), since the Raspberry Pi has extra packages that are normally not available on default Ubuntu or Debian. (Side note: I also have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ myself)

Comment: I tried the 2nd method that resulted in a blank screen and also I tried installing tightvncserver that too failed @wyphan

Comment: Which one is the 2nd method? [This one](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-screen-sharing/)?

Comment: tried  this to start vino server `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` I got this message  
`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display: 
Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options` @wyphan

Comment: `Connection refused` suggests something is wrong with the authentication process. Did you enable password authentication as explained in the guide?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I completely followed the guide and it worked [link](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-screen-sharing/) thanks  @wyphan